# Not able to connect to SQL Server 2012 from current version of DJango and Python

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to connect to `SQL server 2012` using `Pyodbc` and `Django` framework.

But the version of `Django` is `2.1`. Now, when I try to connect using below code when I only have `Pyodbc` installed then the below code doesnot run.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': '{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}', Tried this as well but it did not work.
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'MY_DATABASE',
        # 'HOST': 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX', Tried this as well but it did not work.
        'SERVER': 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX',
        # 'HOST': 'SQLSERVER_InstanceName',
        'PORT': '',
        'USER': 'SQLSERVERUSER',
        'PASSWORD': 'USERs PASSWORD',
        'DATABASE': 'MY_DATABASE',
        # 'Trusted_Connection': 'Yes',
        # 'OPTIONS': {
        #             'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
        #            }
    },
}
```

But when I install `django-pyodbc-azure` and try to run the above code by running `python manage.py inspectdb` command, it works.
But the problem with using `django-pyodbc-azure` is that it downgrades the current version of `django` to `2.0.8` - which I do not want.

I do not want to use `FreeTDS` or `Pymssql`; I want to go with `pyodbc` only.

Can someone please suggest some way for this?

Comment: If you don't want to use the versions that are supported you'll either need to port it yourself or wait for someone else to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, django-pyodbc-azure supports Django 2.1. Below is my configuration.

[image: python virtual environment for django-odbc-azure]

And here is the code that I used to configure the connection.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': "sql_server.pyodbc",
    'HOST': "server_name",
    'USER': "username",
    'PASSWORD': "password",
    'NAME': "database_name",
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
    },
  }
}
```

Note: Don't use the IP address of the server as the HOST, instead use the computer name.