# Django 3.0.5 connection trouble to sql server 2012

Tags: python, django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

I am trying to connect Django 3.0.5 to SQL server 2012 and I went through lots of posts on various websites. they mostly said that use "**django-pyodbc-azure**" but when I go to download that i found out it supports only django 2.1 so is there any other tool or something i am missing or i need to actually do my work only in django 2.1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to connect to SQL Server 2012 from current version of DJango and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791555/not-able-to-connect-to-sql-server-2012-from-current-version-of-django-and-python)

Comment: so according to "thebjong" comment we only have support of django-pyodbc-azure till django2.1 not compatible with django3.

Comment: Look so........